# How to display body content in custom text?

Tags: views

How to display body content in this line?

I had tried "content_body" and "field_body" but doesn't work.

The script below is inserted in "Configure field: Global: Custom text"

```
<li class="one-third column info_item"><a href="[path]" title="[title]" class="pic_info_link_type4">
    <div class="pic_info type4">
        <div class="pic_holder">
            <div class="plus_overlay"></div>
            <div class="plus_overlay_icon"></div>
            [field_image]
            <div class="img_overlay_icon"><span class="portfolio_icon [field_portfolio_format]"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="info_overlay">
            <div class="info_overlay_padding">
                <div class="info_desc"><span class="portfolio_icon [field_portfolio_format]"></span>
                    <h3>[title]</h3>
                    <p>[field_categories]</p>
                    <p>[content_body]</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the custom text box, if you click on "Replacement Patterns" it will show you all the patterns you can use.

Should be `[body]`

Also, make sure all the other fields are arranged above the `Global: Custom text` or else the pattern will not work.